# How to create twitter oauth signature while calling request_token url?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, twitter-oauth, hmacsha1

I want to generate oauth signature for twitter https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token url. I have developed following code but  it will give me message like "Could not authenticate you". Please help me.

```
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import urllib
import time
import requests

oauth_nonce = "40575512181348616041501137897"
oauth_timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
oauth_consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
oauth_callback = ""

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'

test_str = "oauth_nonce="+oauth_nonce+"&oauth_callback="+oauth_callback+"&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp="+oauth_timestamp+"&oauth_consumer_key="+oauth_consumer_key+"&oauth_version=1.0"

test_str = urllib.quote(test_str, safe='')
base_string = "POST&"+test_str

key = consumer_secret + "&"
hashed = hmac.new(key, base_string, sha1)

demo_str = hashed.digest().encode("base64").rstrip('\n')

oauth_signture = urllib.quote(demo_str, safe='')

print oauth_signture

client = requests.Session()
client.headers.update({'Authorization' : 'OAuth oauth_nonce="40575512181348616041501137897", oauth_timestamp="'+oauth_timestamp+'", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="'+oauth_consumer_key+'", oauth_signature="'+oauth_signture+'",oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8069%2Fcallback'})

resp = client.post(url)    
print resp.content
```

Comment: Posting your access tokens on a public website isn't the smartest thing you ever did...

Comment: where i put my access token?